# Sar: what does totsck stand for

Tags: linux, socket, sar

I'm looking for an explanation of the totsck column for the "sar -n SOCK" output

```
09:44:06 PM    totsck    tcpsck    udpsck    rawsck   ip-frag    tcp-tw
09:44:09 PM       580        18         5         0         0         1
09:44:10 PM       580        18         5         0         0         0
09:44:11 PM       580        18         5         0         0         0
Average:          580        18         5         0         0         1
```

It's obviously not the sum of the tcp/udp/raw sockets. The only other explanation I've come around is that it's sockets plus

```
 sysctl fs.file-nr
```

but on my test box that's

```
fs.file-nr = 5632   0   803168
```

Precise explanation much appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit 2:
So apparently totsck is equivalent to**

```
cat /proc/net/sockstat
```

which leads to the question what is counted there. I found [this](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Networking/Regarding-meaning-for-quot-cat-proc-net-sockstat-quot-results/td-p/3922867#.T-MSmDlQp2M) but in the end it only recommends asking the guys who wrote that particular piece of kernel code.

Edit (for domain socket accounting):

```
[root@fedora16 fs]# netstat --protocol unix| wc -l
413
[root@fedora16 fs]# sar -n SOCK 1 1
Linux 3.3.1-5.fc16.x86_64 (fedora16)    06/21/2012  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

10:03:25 PM    totsck    tcpsck    udpsck    rawsck   ip-frag    tcp-tw
10:03:26 PM       598         6         5         0         0         3
Average:          598         6         5         0         0         3
```

Comment: The link to the discussion on sockstat implemetnation is broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's also UNIX domain sockets (STREAM and DGRAM) that are accounted for in total number of sockets used by the system as it seems. UNIX domain sockets are referenced by processes as inodes in the file system. There's a lot of stuff that still uses UNIX domain sockets for various purposes so `sar` picks that up. Check that output of `netstat -a` to see how many UNIX domain sockets are open on your system.

`fs.file-nr` is the number of maximum file handles and while important has nothing to with what you are seeing there on the `sar` output.

Edit:
Please consider that `sar` basically reads `/proc/net/sockstat` and makes an average over that count or reports historical values. It seems that `/proc/net/sockstat` gets the data from two places (kernel source for 2.6.27) and the locations are `net/socket.c` line: 2324 and `net/ipv4/proc.c` line 54 and following and the total number comes from the first locations while the rest is from the second. Going through the `net` structure also reveals what sockets are counted/accounted for and printed into the proc file system.

```
 79  * @SOCK_STREAM: stream (connection) socket
 80  * @SOCK_DGRAM: datagram (conn.less) socket>  
 81  * @SOCK_RAW: raw socket
 82  * @SOCK_RDM: reliably-delivered message>
 83  * @SOCK_SEQPACKET: sequential packet socket
 84  * @SOCK_DCCP: Datagram Congestion Control Protocol socket
```

Comment: Is there any command with which I can count the unix domain sockets (like netstat -t | wc -l for the tcp sockets)?

Comment: Check the output of `netstat --protocol unix | wc -l`.

Comment: Cheers and already thanks, but still doesn't seem to add up (see edit in OP)

Comment: I've just skimmed through the source to see how it's calculated and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Cheers mate, quality answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I had this problem too, with the conclusion that all kernels have this apparent flaw / bug.  I've tested this on 3.10, 4.2, 5.1, and 6.2 kernels, and the code from before 2.6 to 4.16 is unchanged.

So it seems we have leaky sockets!

Consider the following commands:

```
ss -Han |wc -l ;\
awk 'NR==1 { print $NF }' /proc/net/sockstat
```

The output of each command should be about the same (at least 1 socket is created by the first command). But for many of my servers, the output of each command is vastly different.

`sar` gets its information from the `/proc/net/sockstat`, just as we see in the second command. This information is provided by code in the kernel socket driver, explained below.

It's possible both `ss` and `netstat` do not provide an exhaustive list of sockets. That would be a bug or lack of documentation on their part.

It could be the bug is in the code of `net/socket.c`. However, I could not find it. That code handles the allocation and deallocation of all sockets in the system. When it creates a new one, it increments a counter. When it destroys one, it decrements a counter. Pretty simple, should not have room for error.

However, the code does have some hidden complexity in regards to multi-CPU systems. I found that my single-CPU VMs had overall lower discrepencies than my other systems. But these systems are allocated only 1 CPU because they are test systems and not heavily used.
The disparity on my single-CPU systems  is < 10%. But for multi-cpu VMs, there is a wide-variation, from < 1% to a factor of 10!

The per-CPU code in `net/socket.c` looks like this when reporting:

```
        for_each_possible_cpu(cpu)
            counter += per_cpu(sockets_in_use, cpu);
```

The incrementers and decrementers look like:

```
percpu_add(sockets_in_use,1);
...
percpu_sub(sockets_in_use,1);
```

This code hasn't fundamentally changed from before 2005 until 2017, in 4.16 with net-namespaces. But I still experience the discrepancy in versions up to 6.2, so perhaps underneath it's the same code.

These per-cpu macros hide tons of details. I don't understand it all, but maybe I will, after I study [this page](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Concepts/linux-cpu-1.html). Ultimately, it *should* act like a cpu-number indexed array. I imagine this construct is needed so that the kernel running on each CPU can update its own counter to avoid costly spin-locking and possibly cache-flushing. The macros ensure these add/sub operations are atomic. Each counter is an `int`. No bounds checking are performed. Integer math will work correctly even with overflow/underflow across multiple CPUs. And it's very well-known code used all over the place.

Another possibility is that one or more of the memory areas used by the socket counters are corrupted by *other* code in the system.